# RequireJS optimized build still trying to load external jQuery file

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, optimization, requirejs, r.js

I've been working on a Backbone app that uses RequireJS for modularization. I feel I've got a good handle on that, but now that we're ready to deploy, I've been battling with r.js all day and am really stuck. I've managed to get the app to build without any errors, but when I try to run the optimized build, it ignores several files that have been built into my output file. Here's the (edited for brevity) `build.js` file I'm using:

```
({
    appDir: "main-app",
    baseUrl: "js",
    mainConfigFile: "main-app/js/main.js",
    dir: "build",
    optimize: "none", // for debugging this issue
    findNestedDepencencies: false, // 'true' isn't needed, and didn't fix the issue anyway
    removeCombined: true,
    modules: [
        { name: "main", exclude: ["vendor"] },
        { name: "vendor" }
    ],
    wrap: true
})
```

The `main.js` file has been working in non-optimized mode for weeks now. Here's a simplified version of that file:

```
requirejs.config({
    shim: {
        handlebars: { exports: 'Handlebars' },
        underscore: { exports: '_' },
        backbone: { deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'], exports: 'Backbone' },
        marionette: { deps: ['backbone'], exports: 'Marionette' }
    },
    paths: {
        jquery: "vendor/jquery/jquery",
        handlebars: "vendor/handlebars/handlebars",
        backbone: "vendor/backbone/backbone",
        underscore: "vendor/underscore/underscore",
        marionette: "vendor/marionette/backbone.marionette",
        hbs: "vendor/require-handlebars-plugin/hbs"
    },
    hbs: {
        helperDirectory: "common/templates/helpers/"
    }
});

requirejs(['vendor', 'app', 'controllers'], function(Vendor, Application) {
    Application.start();
});
```

Where `vendor` is an empty module that just requires all the 3rd party libraries used, to ensure they're loaded and to make optimization cleaner (I end up with a main.js file with my app code, and a vendor.js file with all the 3rd party code.) The `controllers` file is the same thing, just with most of the application modules instead.

The problem I'm having is that, after compiling and running the optimized application, require is still trying to load `hbs`, `jquery` and `underscore` from the paths listed in the `requirjs.config` block, even though I can see that they are being compiled into `vendor.js`.

```
if ( typeof define === "function" && define.amd ) {
    define( "jquery", [], function() {
        return jQuery;
    });
}
```

I spent a good deal of time trying to get `hbs` compiling, so I'm still trying to determine if that's causing an issue, but I don't know how it would.

Comment: Can you add the contents of your `vendor` module to the question? As simple as it may be, it's still possible to make a mistake in this module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this to work. The core issue had to do with the order of inclusion. In `main.js` I switched the initialization call to this:

```
requirejs(['vendor'], function() {
    requirejs(['app'], function(Application) {
        Application.start();
    });
});
```

Then, in `app.js` (this is a Marionette application):

```
Application.on("initialize:after", function() {
    require(['controllers'], function() {
        ... history, setup, etc...
    });
});
```

Basically, I needed to ensure there were no circular dependencies, which didn't show up during production.

On top of that, I also switched to an AMD-wrapped version of Handlebars, since the shim for that was not working, and switched the `exports` on the Marionette shim to be `Backbone.Marionette`, since `Marionette` wasn't showing up as a global variable.

I found [this article](http://tech.pro/blog/1639/using-rjs-to-optimize-your-requirejs-project) to be extremely helpful in getting most of the way there.

Answer (score 2):

Are you  looking for the [`empy:` directive](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#empty)?

In your build config,

```
({
...
 paths : {
    'jquery' : 'empty:'
 },
})
```

Assigning the path to empty tells r.js it is externally loaded.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. That would work if I were just trying to load jQuery, but the problem is really with all the 3rd party libraries. Require is trying to use the 'paths' config from main.js to load everything, instead of relying on the registered modules that are inlined in `vendor.js`. Incidentally, you can't use a CDN version of a library if it's a dependency of a shimmed module in an optimized build, which is something new I just learned today: [Important optimizer notes for "shim" config](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim)

Comment: @ken.dunnington Ah, I see, I misunderstood your problem.